# Como hago un select para país, departamento, municipio que se filtren dependiendo al pais, o al departamento, e intentado java y ajax y no me sirven

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

En mi formulario estoy tratando de que a la hora de que una persona seleccione un país, los departamentos de este se filtren automáticamente, y a su vez, los municipios de este departamento, pero la verdad no e podido, e consultado mucho codigo de java, ajax y ninguno se adecua ni me ha servido, aclaro que solo tengo conocimiento en php y no en JAVA. Estas tablas entre si tienen la siguiente relacion con llaves foraneas:

Tabla país:
id_pais, pais

Tabla departamento:
id_depa, id_pais(llave foranea), departamento

Tabla municipio:
id_municipio, id_depa(llave foranea), municipio

Aquí el código de los Select que estoy utilizando:

```
<h4>Seleccione su País </h4>
                          <select name="pais" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="pais">Seleccione:</option>
                            <?php

                            
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM pais";
                            $resulta = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)) {
                              $tipo = $row['pais']; 
                              echo "<option value='$tipo'>$tipo</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                          </select>

<h4>Seleccione su Departamento </h4>
                          <select name="departamento" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="departamento">Seleccione:</option>
                            <?php 

                            $query = "SELECT departamento FROM depa";
                            $resulta = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)) {
                              $tipo = $row['departamento'];
                              echo "<option value='$tipo'>$tipo</option>";
                            } 
                            ?>
                          </select>

<h4>Seleccione su Municipio </h4>
                          <select name="municipio" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="municipio">Seleccione:</option>
                            <?php 

                            $query = "SELECT * FROM municipio";
                            $resulta = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)) {
                              $tipo = $row['municipio'];
                              echo "<option value='$tipo'>$tipo</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                          </select>
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin necesidad de usar JAVA ya que la verdad solo se php hasta el momento y no se solucionar ni desenvolverme con lenguaje JAVA, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estimado, lo primero es que java y javascript son lenguajes diferentes. Sobre tu problema, si es posible hacerlo sin javascript, lo cual se hace colocando tus select dentro de un form y cuando se detecta un cambio (onchange) se hace el submit (un POST). Esta es la manera en que se hacía antes del ajax. Lo malo de este método es que la página se recarga cada vez que cambias el valor del select.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].